# Open Graph (and Facebook): the domain <my domain> is not allowed for the specified application id

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

Just got this message from the FB debugging tool :   is not allowed for the specified application id.  I'm trying to post a story using Open Graph on Facebook.  Right now I'm using the Graph API Explorer, but will eventually use the Facebook SDK.

I AM using a different domain from the domain I'm using to host the meta tag URL.  My understanding was that Open Graph needed a publicly accessible page from which to read meta tags.  I was under the impression that this page DID NOT have to live at the same domain as my app.  Is that wrong?  So, does this mean that the page with all the meta tags has to live on the same domain as my web site?

To be clear: the FB app is configured to use domain X, but I'm hosting the OG page on domain Y.  Is that a problem?

**Update:**

Okay, I'm still getting the error this AM.  It seems like I'm getting contradictory info.  Given that this is Facebook support, is there some way I can escalate?

Comment: No, that should not be a problem, as long as you don’t have the migration “Stream post URL security” enabled in your app’s advanced settings.

Comment: Are you using the Graph API explorer's app ID, or your own? If your own, is the domain which contains the URLs you're posting configured in your 'app domains' in the app settings?

Comment: I'm using my own app ID.  And the domain that contains the URL is not in the app domains.  It's an entirely different URL.  It's essentially generic.  If the OG page can live anywhere, then wouldn't that mean that I don't need to domain name configured?

Comment: So, are you saying that if I'm posting from the Graph API I should be using the graph ID?

Comment: Okay, let me make sure I understand this correctly: if I do NOT have have "Stream post URL security" enabled, then I can host my OG page (with the meta tags) anywhere, and I should NOT get this error when I use the debugger: "Object at URL <myurl> of type <mytype> is invalid because the domain <OGDomain> is not allowed for the specified application id <myappid>. You can verify your configured 'App Domain' at...." is that correct?  If that's correct, then I must be missing something, because I'm getting that error at the debugger.

Comment: Also, it works fine and I can see the story in the users activity log if I use http://samples.ogp.me/

Comment: Okay, I'm still getting the error this AM.  It seems like I'm getting contradictory info.  Given that this is Facebook support, is there some way I can escalate?

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know what the issue is, but I was able to get this working by changing my local dev URL to an address that shared the same domain as the URL that was hosting the OG object I needed.

So, locally I've set my environment up to be: mylocal.sample.com, and the OG is hosted at public.sample.com.